# t-sql end of month insert

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

I have created two database tables named TSALESFACT and DimDate. TSALESFACT table contains the monthly sales target values. And DimTime contains the date values which begins from 01/01/2005.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TSalesFact](
[DateID] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[YearID] [int] NOT NULL,
[MonthID] [int] NOT NULL,
[SeasonID] [char](10) NOT NULL,
[DepartmentID] [char](10) NOT NULL,
[SalesAmount] [int] NOT NULL
```

)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dim_Date](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Day] [char](2) NOT NULL,
[DaySuffix] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
[DayOfWeek] [varchar](9) NOT NULL,
[DOWInMonth] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[DayOfYear] [int] NOT NULL,
[WeekOfYear] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[WeekOfMonth] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[Month] [char](2) NOT NULL,
[MonthName] [varchar](9) NOT NULL,
[Quarter] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[QuarterName] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
[Year] [char](4) NOT NULL,
[StandardDate] [varchar](10) NULL,
[HolidayText] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

I would like to INSERT these sales target values into a new table named DailySalesTargets. **But, the main purpose of this operation is writing the target sales to the each of end of month date**. All of the date values for the relevant month will be zero. My desired resultset for this operation is like below:

[image: DesiredResultset]

How can I achieve this? Any idea?

Comment: does the SalesFact have a row for each day?

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Original TSalesFact table contains only monthly sales target values. But the desired resultset should contain each day values. These complete day values will be set to zero. But the end of month value will receive data from the TSalesFact month data.

Comment: This is not a normal pattern for a monthly target fact. It's usually not necessary to fill in empty days within the month. First consider: why do you need to do this? It's easy to do with an appropriate insert / select but I suspect it's unnecessary

Comment: should you do this for each DepartmentId?

Comment: @vkp Unfortunately yes. Both for department ID and SeasonID. My TSalesFact table contains only YearID and MonthID. I could not convert it to a original date format. INSERT INTO TSALESFACT2 
 SELECT EOMONTH(Date) from tsales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
insert into [DailySalesTargets]([DateID],[YearID],[MonthID],
                                [SeasonID],[DepartmentID],[SalesAmount])
select d.[Date],d.[Year],d.[Month]
,dptSeason.[SeasonID],dptSeason.[DepartmentID]
,case when EOMONTH(d.[Date])=s.[DateID] then s.[SalesAmount] else 0 end as [SalesAmount]
from [dbo].[dim_Date] d
cross join (select distinct [DepartmentID],[SeasonID] from [dbo].[TSalesFact]) dptSeason
left join [dbo].[TSalesFact] s on d.[Date] = s.[DateID] 
and s.[DepartmentID]=dptSeason.[DepartmentID]
and s.[SeasonID]=dptSeason.[SeasonID]
```